# how to add a for loop data to form.serializer() - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send dynamic two input field to backend via ajax, and i have main form, the main form works fine, dont know how to send two extra dynamic inputs to backend, here is my code

```js
var extra_inputs = 2
var removed_extra_inputs = []
var formData = new FormData();

for(var i=0; i<extra_inputs; i++){
  try{
      formData.append("guestinfo-"+i, document.getElementById("guestinfo-"+i).value);
      formData.append("reason-"+i, document.getElementById("reason-"+i).value);
      }
  catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      }
  }

  const form = document.getElementById('post-form-add-booking')    
        
  const url = window.location.href
  const room = parseInt(room_number)
  form.addEventListener("submit",submitHanler);
  function submitHanler(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:url,
           data:$("#post-form-add-booking").serialize() + "&extra_inputs="+extra_inputs + '&removed_extra_inputs='+removed_extra_inputs,
           dataType:'json',
           success:successFunction,
           error:errorFunction,
                            
       })        
     }
```

but not sure is there a way to combine formData with form.serilaizer please , thank you for you your help ..

Comment: i changed my code, and forget that remove it

Comment: @mplungjan as i mention the main form works fine, but for the other not work

Comment: @mplungjan i could fix that because of your advices, cant thank you enough

Comment: I made an update to my answer - it is simpler now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I believe you mean

```
$('#post-form-add-booking').on("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(this); // adding the DOM form
  $("[id^=guestinfo], [id^=reason]").each(function() {
    formData.append(this.id, this.value)
  })
  $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:url,
       data:formData,
       dataType:'json',
       success:successFunction,
       error:errorFunction,
   })    
})
```